# python to fortran what equivalent of append?

Tags: python, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to re-write this function in python to find all path between two nodes of a graph and make a subroutine in Fortran 90:

```
def find_all_paths2(graph, start, end):
    path  = []
    paths = []
    queue = [(start, end, path)]
    while queue:
        start, end, path = queue.pop()
        print queue
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            paths.append(path)
        for node in set(graph[start]).difference(path):
            queue.append((node, end, path))
    return paths
```

I have two questions:

- I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to `append` an array in Fortran? (do I need to reserve a huge memory space?)
- is there any built in function in Fortran equivalent to `set()`?

Comment: Why Fortran 90 and not Fortran 2003+?  That changes a lot.

Comment: Regarding the first question: Look up ["Amortized analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). With a clever shrink and expand algorithm (overallocation) you can make `append`s behave with amoritized `O(1)`

Comment: @francescalus : I will need to include in a bigger project, where everybody is working in fortran90...

Comment: Maybe better to start writing the subroutine and when you encounter issues ask about these specific issues or if it works correctly you may ask on CodeReview for performance tipps. But "how to translate this code to fortran" is just too broad.

Comment: @Mseifert I already start to translate but I was just wondering if there were some good practice in fortran to append list, what I'm not able do do yet. But I have stopped trying going directly to fortran, I will try to re-write in python without using `append` and `set()` and then go to fortran... Thanks !

Comment: @Dadep They say they work in Fortran 90 or how do you know that? Almost no-one is writing in that old version, but in Fortran 95 or 2003+. There are no Fortran 90 only compilers available anyway.

Comment: There are no lists in Fortran unless you use some library or implement your own...

Comment: @VladimirF I was thinking use array until list.... here I just add subroutine in a bigger code with a .f90 extension compiled by ifort. can I put function of other fortran in it ?  (sorry I'm very ignorant about how all of this work...)

Comment: Yes, *any* Fortran can be in a .f90 file.

Comment: A Python list is a buffer with some growth room.  `append` adds a new pointer to this buffer.  When it runs out of growth room it gets a new larger buffer block, copying pointers if needed.  A Python `set` is a hash table, like dictionary with keys but no values.